# Motorcycle lost all acceleration on highway and now has no power to go into gear. Kawasaki Ninja 400 ABS

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, kawasaki, ninja

This is the second time something similar like this has happened. The last time, I was in 2nd gear taking off and the bike just wouldn't accelerate further. After stopping the bike, throttling the bike in first will not produce any power to the wheels and I just kind of rev.

I took the bike to the shop. They said they fixed the problem relating to the clutch. I asked the mechanic what caused it and explained the situation which happened before hand. He said that honestly shouldn't have caused any problems and he wasn't 100% sure what caused the problem; I took it back, this was Septemberish 2019.

I should clarify that the bike was in a minor accident early on. Collision/side swipe with a vehicle. At the time the shop I work with said there was no mechanical damage and it was all cosmetic. I am somewhat wondering if this problem is a remnant of that accident.

Now into the new season, I was driving on the highway, and traffic began to slow down to around 100km/hr. I rev-matched and as traffic began to pick-back up I started to accelerate but noticed my acceleration rate wasn't as it normally would have been for how much I was throttling.

Slowly but surely, the rate of acceleration loss began to increase until I stopped on the side of the road. Now putting the bike into first gear and throttling doesn't move the bike at all. Same issue as before, just at higher speeds.

What could this issue possibly be that it keeps happening time and time again. Is there something I should be watching out with that I'm riding wrong? Or is this a common issue?

Comment: I should also note, the bike is rather new. Only 7000km on it to date.

Comment: What maintenance has been done? lubrication, adjustments etc?

Comment: Considering your history of clutch problems, I'm going to suggest that you still have a clutch problem.